# Format Color Scale

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, format

I have a macro which provides  matrix and I only want to put those matrix under a color scale format (see below), this has been done manualy:

Expected output: [image]

the most closer I got is this format, which means the opposite:

Current output:
[image]

what I used to do so is:

```
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B3:BA26").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
```

I tried with many numbers of color type but only 2 and 3 seem to run but do not yield my expected output.

Thank you for your help

And this way does not work neither,  (I have actually 8 matrix)

```
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B3:BA26").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B29:BA52").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
Sheets("Hoja2").Range("B55:BA78").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
Sheets("Hoja2").Range("B81:BA104").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2

Sheets("Hoja2").Range("B3:BA26").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
Sheets("Hoja2").Range("B29:BA52").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B55:BA78").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B81:BA104").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2


FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
```

Comment: you can use macro recorder whilst selecting range then go to  home > conditional formatting  > colour scales and  choose second to right at top (darkest colour for highest number)

Comment: It will return 3 colorscalecriteria (type) covering xlConditionValueLowestValue, xlConditionValuePercentile and xlConditionValueHighestValue

Comment: Thanks, so for you there is not direct VBA command which would allow to do it directly?

Comment: yes. the macro recorder would record the necessary code. I outlined what the key elements you would see are. If you have the developer tab added into your ribbon you can access the macro recorder to record the code required as you perform the manual formatting (via home > conditional formatting >etc......) [Macro Recorder](http://www.contextures.com/excel-macro-record-test.html)

Comment: Have you tried adding the condition `FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue` after that line you showed us?

Comment: Thank you and apologies for my late reply,  do you mean I could do: Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B3:BA26").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3                                                                                               FormatConditions(3).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue

Comment: No, do `Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B3:BA26").FormatConditions.AddColorSc‌​ale ColorScaleType:=3`    `FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue`. Check my answer and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Still does not work ... but thank you very much for your help and time

Comment: What error are you getting? I just tested what I told you, both in this comment and in my answer and it worked for me, so let me know what's wrong on your case.

Comment: The error is at :     FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue, it returns, sub or function no defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
With FormatConditions(1)
    'Define the color for your lowest value
    .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = 8109667

    'Define the type of definition for the mid value. The default is 50%.
    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    'Define the color for your mid-point value
    .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = 8711167

    'Define the color for your highest value
    .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = 7039480

End With
```

Of course, this is to give you complete freedom over the result of your conditional format. Considering all you want is one of the default styles, my comment should be enough.